# Creating an Index Column for a Descriptive Data Using “DAX” in Power BI

Tags: powerbi, dax

I have a table Like this,

**Table1**

[image]

I want to create a column called as Row Number using DAX and not Query Editor (M).

So the Expected output is,

[image]

This can be done in M - Power Query Side.

But, I am looking for a solution using DAX- Calculated Column.

Additional source data

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The RANKX function should work fine for this purpose.

```
Row Number = RANKX ( Table1, Table1[ColA] )
```

Recommended reading:

https://radacad.com/how-to-use-rankx-in-dax-part-1-of-3-calculated-columns

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply. When I try to apply your solutions it will give the same count for this type of data.....can you please advise. Data in column in A ....ITEM
56789
56789
56789
56789
56789
4564578
4564578
4564578
4564578
4564578
4564578
4564578
4564578
4564578
878-DP
890
264156

Comment: I add image on the top. enter image description here.  Example 56789 giving count for 3 but I want count of duplicate as well.....56789-1, 56789-2

Comment: That seems different than your "Expected output" example where both `Mango` rows have the same index. Can you clarify what you're asking for?

Comment: Your solutions working well. I understand but when I try to apply the same logic why it will give a different result? In mango place I have a number 56789. Can you please advise.

Comment: What result are you expecting instead of what's in the screenshot?

Comment: Count duplicated as well. Example. in my data table 56789 repeated 5 time so my expected result is 56789 1, 56789 2, 56789 3, 56789 4, 56789 5.

Comment: In Excel I am applying the following formula =COUNTIF($A$2:$A2,A2) in order to get the  duplication of count. https://www.extendoffice.com/documents/excel/5942-excel-running-count-of-occurrence.html. This is exactly I am looking for in Power BI.

Comment: I am not sure I can request one more help here regrading Power BI query. https://superuser.com/questions/1618391/discount-from-data-table-to-report-table-in-power-bi-desktop-new-calculated-col. Can you please advise when you have a time. Please

Comment: This is a fine place to ask for help but it seems like you're asking a different question in these comments than in your post. I still can't follow why `Mango` has the same index in your example but you seem to be wanting something entirely different in the comments. If you have a separate question, please create a separate post.